# Combine Angularjs and java in the same server

Tags: java, angularjs

I want to develop a web-server with java and to create an angularjs interface to configure the server. Right know I have two separate apps. I want to combine them in a way that when the server start it also start and serve the angularjs interface. Do you have an idea if this is possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You need a web server to host some Angular. That's really all you are asking

Comment: Put the Angular app inside you web content folder.

Comment: what do you mean with _develop a web-server_? Really write your own server or an applicaiton that will be deployed/installed to/in a web server?

Comment: I mean an application with a REST interface to be deployed on a server and to communication with a mobile device

Answer (score 0):

If they're completly separated apps (no session, no server side pages rendered...) you just have to use some webserver (Apache would do) to serve the static Angular/JS+CSS+HTML.

This way you can keep them both separated and develop the Java app as an API (REST I guess you're using).

Answer (score 0):

The management MUST be only 'an application' for your server; must be like the rest of applications in it.

It must have the same parameters to configure it that the rest of applications use in your web-server, whit, obviously, different permissions.

This way your web-server will be coherent.

And obviously, your server should start serving all the configured apps on server start, so your management app -if configured- will then be served when server starts.